# QT umount() function doesn't work

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi

When i write down this code ;

```
int removeUSB = umount("/media/pi/USB_Device");
if(!removeUSB) 
   qDebug()<<"USB is removed."; 
else 
   qDebug()<<"USB is not removed."
```

USB can not be removed.I'm taking "USB is not removed" message in debug screen.
What am i missing ? Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `umount` function you are calling is not a QT function, it is a function provided by the glibc library. See: [umount(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/umount) man page and [glibc documentation for mount/umount](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mount_002dUnmount_002dRemount.html).

Both of those pages say that if the unmount call is not successful, it returns -1 and sets the global variable `errno` to an error code. Error codes can be found on the [errno](https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) man page.

You could see the error as follows:

```
if(umount("/media/pi/USB_Device")) 
   qDebug()<<"Error removing USB Deviced: " << strerror(errno); 
else 
   qDebug()<<"USB is removed."
```

The `strerror` function translates the error code to a human readable string.

Possible reasons for not being able to unmount the device include:

- Your process, or some other process, might have a file in the device open, in which case the errno returned would be EBUSY. The command `lsof` can be very useful to determine which process is keeping the filesystem busy.
- The user that is running the process might not have the required permission, in which case the error code would be EPERM.

Comment: i rewrite code like you said.I took a a permission message in debug screen "operation not permitted".How can i solve this problem ??

Comment: That is the error EPERM i mentioned in my answer. The user your process is running as does not have permission to unmount. Try running it as root.